# Implementing MILP in PULP with restricted choices of group

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp, integer-programming

I am trying to implement the following problem in PULP:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4232797/optimising-class-assignment-based-on-test-score-and-class-choice/4233234#4233234

Here is my attempt so far. I am not sure how to build the dictionary "student_allocations" into my restrictions to stop students being assigned to groups they did not choose. Any help is appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pulp import * 

# student ID number
student_id = np.arange(1,31)

# Test Scores
scores = [15, 29, 18, 74, 66, 89, 3, 77, 78, 70, 68, 47, 71, 37, 96, 27, 76, 25, 95, 16, 32, 11, 81, 82, 21, 57, 8, 5, 55, 31]

# Test scores mapped to student ID to make parameter s_i
s_i= dict(zip(student_id, scores))

# Groups
GROUPS = ['A','B','C','D','E','F'] 

# Student ID mapped to Group choices
student_allocations = {1: ['F', 'D'], 2: ['F', 'E', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C'], 3: ['E', 'D'], 4: ['D', 'E', 'C', 'B', 'A'], 5: ['F', 'C', 'D'], 6: ['E', 'D', 'C', 'A'], 7: ['A'], 8: ['C', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'F'], 9: ['F', 'B'], 10: ['D', 'E'], 11: ['A', 'E', 'C', 'B', 'D'], 12: ['D', 'E', 'A', 'F'], 13: ['E'], 14: ['C', 'F', 'D'], 15: ['E', 'A', 'F', 'C', 'D'], 16: ['C', 'D', 'F', 'A', 'E'], 17: ['E', 'F'], 18: ['B'], 19: ['C', 'E', 'B', 'D'], 20: ['F', 'E'], 21: ['E', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'F', 'C'], 22: ['D', 'B', 'F', 'E', 'C', 'A'], 23: ['D', 'A', 'F', 'B', 'C'], 24: ['E', 'F', 'B', 'D', 'A'], 25: ['C'], 26: ['F', 'E', 'B'], 27: ['A', 'D', 'B'], 28: ['E', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 29: ['A', 'B', 'F', 'C', 'E', 'D'], 30: ['A', 'F', 'B', 'D']}


# setting the problem variable
prob = LpProblem("Timetabling", LpMinimize)

# define decision variable
x_ic = LpVariable.dicts("InClass", [(i,c) for i in student_id
                                          for c in GROUPS],
                       0,1,LpBinary)             

# define dummy min, max variables
l_c = LpVariable.dicts("lowest group score",GROUPS,0)      
h_c = LpVariable.dicts("highest group score",GROUPS,0)    

# define the objective function 
prob += lpSum(h_c[c] - l_c[c] for c in GROUPS) 

# setting the constraints
# constraint 1      
for i in student_id:
    prob += lpSum(x_ic[(i,c)] for c in GROUPS) == 1 
       
# constraint 2
N = 10  # maximum class size
for c in GROUPS:
    prob += lpSum(x_ic[(i,c)] for i in student_id) <= N
    
# constraint 3
for i in student_id:
    for c in GROUPS:
        prob += (l_c[c] - s_i[i]) <= (1-s_i[i]) * (1-x_ic[(i,c)])   

# constraint 4
for i in student_id:
    for c in GROUPS:
        prob += h_c[c] >= s_i[i] * x_ic[(i,c)]

# solve the problem
prob.solve()
print("Status: ", LpStatus[prob.status])

# output allocations
TOL = 0.000001 
for i in student_id:
    for c in GROUPS:
        if x_ic[(i,c)].varValue > TOL:
            print(i, c)
```

EDIT: Full solution given below with Method 3 incorporated into decision variable, constraints and output.

```
# setting the problem variable
prob = LpProblem("Timetabling", LpMinimize)

# define decision variable
x_ic = LpVariable.dicts("InClass", [(i,c) for i in student_id
                                          for c in student_allocations[i]
                                          ],
                       0,1,LpBinary)              

# define dummy min, max variables
l_c = LpVariable.dicts("lowest group score",GROUPS,0)      
h_c = LpVariable.dicts("highest group score",GROUPS,0)   


# define the objective function 
prob += lpSum(h_c[c] - l_c[c] for c in GROUPS) 

# setting the constraints
            
# constraint 1      
for i in student_id:
    prob += lpSum(x_ic[(i,c)] for c in GROUPS if c in student_allocations[i]) == 1 
       
# constraint 2
N = 10 # maximum class size
for c in GROUPS:
        prob += lpSum(x_ic[(i,c)] for i in student_id if c in student_allocations[i]) <= N
    
# constraint 3
for i in student_id:
    for c in GROUPS:
        if c in student_allocations[i]:
            prob += (l_c[c] - s_i[i]) <= (1-s_i[i]) * (1-x_ic[(i,c)])   

# constraint 4
for i in student_id:
    for c in GROUPS:
        if c in student_allocations[i]:
            prob += h_c[c] >= s_i[i] * x_ic[(i,c)]

# solve the problem
prob.solve()
print("Status: ", LpStatus[prob.status])

# output allocations
TOL = 0.000001 
for i in student_id:
    for c in GROUPS:
        if c in student_allocations[i]:
            if x_ic[(i,c)].varValue > TOL:
                print(i,c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, some obvious, some a bit more work.

#### Method 1: add constraints

Add constraints that forbid assignments to a group that is not allowed:

```
for i in student_id:
    for c in GROUPS:
        if not (c in student_allocations[i]):
            prob += x_ic[(i,c)] == 0
```

This is rather obvious, and I think you should have been able to figure this out.

#### Method 2: add bounds

A slightly more sophisticated approach would be to set upper bounds.

```
for i in student_id:
    for c in GROUPS:
        if not (c in student_allocations[i]):
             x_ic[(i,c)].upBound = 0
```

This is a little bit more efficient, as no constraints are being generated, but rather simple upper bounds. A solver will typically convert singleton constraints to bounds, but this can save some effort generating the constraints.

#### Method 3: sparse variables

This is the most efficient way. Only generate the allowed variables. Change the variable to:

```
# define decision variable
x_ic = LpVariable.dicts("InClass", [(i,c) for i in student_id
                                          for c in GROUPS
                                          if c in student_allocations[i]],
                       0,1,LpBinary)
```

or shorter:

```
# define decision variable
x_ic = LpVariable.dicts("InClass", [(i,c) for i in student_id
                                          for c in student_allocations[i]],
                       0,1,LpBinary)
```

You need to protect the corresponding constraints as well. For large models, this is the best approach. For production models, I always use this method.

Comment: Just to be clear, when applying method 3, the output would also need to be modified as well as the constraints? It seems to get it work it needs to be:                                                
# output allocations
TOL = 0.000001 
for i in student_id:
    for c in GROUPS:                                                                                                                   
      if c in student_allocations[i]:
         if x_ic[(i,c)].varValue > TOL:
            print(i, c)

Comment: Yes, you should only use valid combinations (obviously?)